# Exact meaning of doctor's office

Tags: sentence-meaning

There are two sentences in Betty S. Azar grammar book that I can't get exact meaning of those.

1. Did you drive to the doctor's office?
2. Did you go to a doctor?

First, what is **"doctor's office"**? and Where do we call Doctor's office.

Second, what is the difference between those sentences meaning?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: In BrE (but not so much in AmE, I think), we're more likely to refer to *the doctor's **surgery***. But whether or not to explicitly include a noun (as opposed to asking, for example, *Have you been to the doctor['s]?*) largely depends on whether you're thinking in terms of the *physical location,* or the person you might see there. Often that's a fine nuance where it really doesn't make any difference which way you express yourself.

Comment: The first sentence asks if you actually drove a car to the location where the doctor works (The doctor's office).  The second is asking if you have seen a doctor - implying that there is something wrong with you and that you had reason to do so.  Internally, I transpose the second sentence to: "Did you see a doctor?"

Comment: Google Ngrams shows that "doctor's office" is more common than "doctor's surgery", even in British English. If there is a difference, a hospital doctor might have an office but see all the patients in the wards.

Comment: I don't trust Google Ngrams to distinguish accurately between BrE and AmE. I don't think Ngrams shows anything about the relevant frequency in BrE. NGrams would have us believe that in BrE, "honor" and "humor" are outnumbered 4:1 and 3:1 respectively by "honour" and "humour". I am pretty sure the truth is closer to 99:1. Anyway, in BrE a hospital doctor has an "office", whereas a family doctor or GP has a "surgery" (where surgery is *not* performed) (though a surgery could contain several rooms, some called offices). Also in BrE, a surgeon takes the title "Mr", while a GP takes the title "Dr".

Comment: GloWbE (the corpus of Web-based English) disagrees. It shows "doctor's surgery' a little more common than "doctor's office" in GB (110:100), IE (28:23), and AU (50:48). In NZ it has about a third the frequency (9:23) and everywhere else it hardly occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Doctor's office** is a private place owned by a doctor (or several doctors) where medical visits to doctors take place. It usually consists of a waiting room and an examination room and patients should pay for doctor's visit to be examined by the doctor.

About the difference between these two sentences, I think the second one is a general question asked from someone to see whether he/she has visited a doctor for his/her illness. (The place where a doctor is working is not important here. It can be an office, a hospital, a clinic or ...)

About the first question, I think it highly depends on the answer. The person who asks the question may want to know if you have gone to the office using a car:

> Did you **drive to** the doctor's office?

Or to be sure that the place you have driven, has been the doctor's office (not anywhere else):

> Did you drive to **the doctor's office**?

Comment: Probably most doctors are not the only owner of the "office" and many work for a hospital or clinic. That is a minor issue. I think the important thing is that we need context to understand the reason _drive_ is stated explicitly. There is no need to say _drive_ explicitly unless there is something more that is not stated here.

Answer (score 0):

A doctor's office is a facility where you can visit a medical doctor for consultation or minor procedures. For example, family doctors, dermatologists, and urologists would usually be seen in a doctor's office. Major surgeries usually do not occur at a doctor's office, but instead, take place in the operation room of a hospital. However, a surgeon would usually have an office where he could see patients before or after their surgery. The term "doctor's office" is usually used to talk about a place where patients are welcome; if a doctor did not work with patients, like an epidemiologist, then the place where he worked would just be called something like a "lab" or a "medical facility."

The term "doctor's" is just a shorter way  of referring to a doctor's office.